# Why not 'safely' ? 'It would make it almost impossible for promisors to order their affairs safe in the knowledge'

Tags: grammaticality, legalese

[*O'Sullivan & Hilliard's The Law of Contract*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OSullivan-Hilliards-Law-Contract-Janet/dp/0198807821/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) (2018 8 ed). p 122.

> 5.99 There are three plausible alternative candidates. First, a requirement of form might
>   be introduced, so that, for example, only promises made in writing were enforceable.
>   But this would be unworkable in modern society, where many thousands of oral
>   transactions are made every day. Second, more emphasis could be given to the requirement
>   that the promisor intended to create legal relations. This is a much more realistic
>   alternative, reflecting the position in many civilian jurisdictions that even a gratuitous
>   promise is enforceable if it was made seriously with the intention of attracting legal
>   effect. It has the advantage of flexibility, allowing a court to explore whether a particular
>   promise was seriously made and whether on the facts it should or should not be enforced.
>   But with flexibility comes uncertainty: the parties could not be certain until the
>   matter was litigated whether or not their particular promise was enforceable. Of course,
>   rules might grow up to encourage certainty, whereby a promisor might be deemed to
>   have intended to create legal relations in certain circumstances—but the chances are
>   those rules would not be so very different from the rules of consideration. A third
>   possibility is to choose reliance as the relevant filter and to allow any promise to be
>   enforced, but only once it has been relied on by the promisee. For all its apparent fairness,
>   this approach has significant disadvantages. It would make it almost impossible
>   for promisors to order their affairs **safe** in the knowledge that their promise either was
>   or was not enforceable, since enforceability would not ‘kick in’ until some time after
>   the promise was made, when the other party relied on it for the first time. Promisors
>   would be obliged to keep track of the actions of the other party—not a very attractive

p 123.

> prospect commercially. Furthermore, ‘reliance’ is a slippery concept (as we have seen
>   in our discussion of estoppel): it is hard to imagine first instance courts reaching and
>   applying a consistent, generally acceptable definition of reliance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Safe does not go with 'order their affairs'. It modifies 'promisors'. It would be impossible for them to be **safe in the knowledge** that their promise was or was not enforceable when they ordered their affairs.